# Stop <p> tags from wrapping onto a new line

Tags: html, css

I have some content in a `<p>`tag. For some reason in IE<8 (Possibly greater than 8 too) the content of the last `<p>`tag on a line wraps around.

Is there anyway to stop this from happening ?

Example [link](http://styxofdynamite.bitnamiapp.com/wordboxes.php?words%5B%5D=hello&words%5B%5D=my&words%5B%5D=baby&words%5B%5D=hello&words%5B%5D=my&words%5B%5D=darling&words%5B%5D=hello&words%5B%5D=my&words%5B%5D=good&words%5B%5D=time&words%5B%5D=girl&words%5B%5D=&words%5B%5D=&words%5B%5D=&words%5B%5D=)

N.B The actual form will use post rather than get, I've just changed it so I could link to the results.

### My HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <p>
        <span class="letter taller"></span>
        <span class="letter"></span>
        <span class="letter taller"></span>
        <span class="letter hanging"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

### My CSS

```
.letter {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    padding-top 1.618em;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1.618em;
    padding-top: 5em;
}
.taller, .hanging {
    height: 4em;
}
.hanging {
    position: relative;
    top: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant code to the body of the question. Questions on StackOverflow about code should always contain the code in the question, instead of behind a link.

Comment: @rlemon That's fixed it. Definitely a trick to remember - thanks

Comment: I added an answer with the same information then.

Comment: I find it absolutely hilarious that I'm about to answer one of your questions again. I feel like a creep. I don't have IE though - could you actually show some screenshots of how it looks there?

Comment: I'll include screenshots next time I can get to an IE box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add `white-space: nowrap` to the `p` tag css and it will stop the wrapping.

you can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score -1):

If I am interpeting the question correctly, you can use `&nbsp;`. I would suggest overflow-x, except IE8 doesn't understand it.